# WordPress Custom Metadata Plugin reorders fields

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, metadata, field

I'm using WordPress' [Custom Metadata Plugin](https://github.com/Automattic/custom-metadata) to add metadata groups to a site I'm working on.

What I want to do is add a custom field with the ability to add more custom fields as needed, like this:[image: the admin panel view of my custom fields]

But when I publish the posts, it messes up the input order, like this:
[image: when i enter data, it randomly reorders it.]

Here's my code. The multiple fields are being created at the bottom of the `x_add_metadata_field` function, with `multiple=> true`.

```
function myfunction_x_init_cw_fields(){
  if( function_exists( 'x_add_metadata_field' ) && function_exists( 'x_add_metadata_group' ) ) {
$post_types = array( 'page' );
$args = array(
  'label' => 'Include Content Widgets', // Label for the group
  'context' => 'normal', // (post only)
  'priority' => 'default', // (post only)
  'autosave' => false //, // (post only) Should the group be saved in autosave? NOT IMPLEMENTED YET!
  //'exclude' => '', // posts#s to exclude
  //'include' => '', // posts#s to include
);
x_add_metadata_group( 'myfunction_cw_details', $post_types, $args );

x_add_metadata_field( 'myfunction_page_cw_field', $post_types, array(
  'group' => 'myfunction_cw_details', // the group name
  'description' => esc_html('Enter content widget slug under "content widgets"'),
  'label' => 'Content Widget Slugs',
  'multiple' => true
));
}
}

add_action( 'custom_metadata_manager_init_metadata', 'myfunction_x_init_cw_fields' );
```

Basically, I'm hoping someone will say "Hey, there's a setting to order the results that isn't mentioned in the docs."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding these to your args:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

E.g

```
x_add_metadata_field( 'myfunction_page_cw_field', $post_types, array(
  'group' => 'myfunction_cw_details', // the group name
  'description' => esc_html('Enter content widget slug under "content widgets"'),
  'label' => 'Content Widget Slugs',
  'multiple' => true,
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC' 
));
```